# Implementing one's own linked ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, set

I was looking at implementing my own linked ArrayList with methods such as `add`, `indexOf`, `remove`, etc. However, I can't quite seem to understand how a `set` function that returns the generic object that replaces the old one at a specific index.

Something along the lines of

```
public E set(int index, E element
{
    E elementAtIndex;
    //some code
    return elementAtIndex;
}
```

Could someone help explain the psuedocode for the `set` method?

Comment: The term "linked array list" is confusing as "linked" and "array" are usually mutually exclusive.  Your question is also confusing since the documentation for the `set()` method is pretty clear.  What part do you not understand?  We cannot explain `// some code` in your pseudocode as only you know what you want it to do.

Comment: Well I'm trying to implement my own class rather than use the built-in documentation, which is why I was asking for the psuedocode.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the "linked" prefix is not relevant for ArrayList, as it already has the iteration order clearly defined, which is basically the increasing order of its index. It may be relevant for HashMap as in the case of LinkedHashMap.

Coming to psuedocode explanation for the set method,

```
public E set (int index, E newValue){
    If index < 0 or index >= listSize  // check whether the index is within the range
        then throw IndexOutOfBoundsException  //   throw appropriate exception

    oldValue = backingElementArray[index]   // temporarily store the old value at the index
    backingElementArray[index] = newValue   // replace the old value with new one
    return oldValue   // return the old value

}
```

Hope this helps. :)